# Clear Vector source without recursively calling the sources loader method

Tags: openlayers

OpenLayers v4.6.5:

---

```
       var source = new ol.source.Vector({
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
            loader: function() {
                return $.ajax({
                  url: myURL
                }).then(function(response){
                   var geoJsonReader = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
                   var newFeatures = geoJsonReader.readFeaturesFromObject({
                     type: "FeatureCollection",
                     features: response.features
                   });
                   source.clear(); /** This calls the loader recursively */
                   source.addFeatures(newFeatures);         
                });
            },
            strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
        })
```

In the code above, I try to re-add all newly retrieved features every time the source is loaded, after clearing the source. 
However, every time I call the `clear` method on the source, the loader gets triggered againg (via the `changed` event), leaving me in an endless recursion. How do I avoid that?

---

This is the respective stack Trace:

```
ol.source.Vector.clear  @   js:62564
onFeatureCollectionLoaded   @   js:110894
(anonymous) @   jquery.min.js:2
i   @   jquery.min.js:2
fireWith    @   jquery.min.js:2
y   @   jquery.min.js:4
c   @   jquery.min.js:4
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)     
send    @   jquery.min.js:4
ajax    @   jquery.min.js:4
query   @   js:113058
getData @   js:110862
loader  @   js:110523
ol.source.Vector.loadFeatures   @   js:62947
ol.renderer.canvas.VectorLayer.prepareFrame @   js:33475
ol.renderer.canvas.Map.renderFrame  @   js:28899
ol.PluggableMap.renderFrame_    @   js:21137
(anonymous) @   js:20052
requestAnimationFrame (async)       
ol.PluggableMap.render  @   js:21028
boundListener   @   js:9705
ol.events.EventTarget.dispatchEvent @   js:10125
ol.Observable.changed   @   js:10293
ol.layer.Group.handleLayerChange_   @   js:19705
boundListener   @   js:9705
ol.events.EventTarget.dispatchEvent @   js:10125
ol.Observable.changed   @   js:10293
ol.layer.Layer.handleSourceChange_  @   js:21816
boundListener   @   js:9705
ol.events.EventTarget.dispatchEvent @   js:10125
ol.Observable.changed   @   js:10293
ol.source.Vector.clear  @   js:62564
onFeatureCollectionLoaded
```

Comment: Try `source.clear({fast: true});`.

Comment: does not make any difference (`source.clear` takes only a boolean argument, looking at the API)

Comment: This argument is named option, and syntax for options is as above.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use ol v4.6.5

Comment: I couldn't reproduce recursive behaviour when using `source.clear()`.

Comment: I finally managed to reproduce this behaviour. Source of GeoJSON has to be external file, not variable. See solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem of recursive calls can be solved by introducing `clearingInProgress` variable, which tells when `clear()` was called and so loading has to be skipped:

```
var clearingInProgress = false;

var source = new ol.source.Vector({
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  loader: function() {
    if (clearingInProgress) {
      clearingInProgress = false;
      return;
    }
    return $.ajax({
      url: myURL
    }).then(function(response){
       var geoJsonReader = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
       var newFeatures = geoJsonReader.readFeaturesFromObject({
         type: "FeatureCollection",
         features: response.features
       });
       clearingInProgress = true;
       source.clear(); 
       source.addFeatures(newFeatures);         
    });
  },
  strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
});
```